# PHP extension oauth missing error while trying to setup UserVoice PHP SDK

Tags: php, oauth, uservoice

I am trying to setup the UserVoice PHP SDK in my local machine using Composer. I am following the manual specified at https://developer.uservoice.com/docs/api/php-sdk/. I have both oauth and mcrypt php extensions enabled.

The composer.js files contains the following,

```
{
  "require": {
    "uservoice/uservoice": ">=0.0.6"
  }
}
```

But when I try `php composer.phar install` command, I am getting the following errors in terminal.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - uservoice/uservoice 0.0.9 requires ext-oauth * -> the requested PHP extension oauth is missing from your system.
    - uservoice/uservoice 0.0.8 requires ext-oauth * -> the requested PHP extension oauth is missing from your system.
    - uservoice/uservoice 0.0.7 requires ext-oauth * -> the requested PHP extension oauth is missing from your system.
    - uservoice/uservoice 0.0.6 requires ext-oauth * -> the requested PHP extension oauth is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for uservoice/uservoice >=0.0.6 -> satisfiable by uservoice/uservoice[0.0.6, 0.0.7, 0.0.8, 0.0.9].
```

php.ini file is configured with the extensions. I have tried restarting the apache server after installation of these extension, still issue persists.

what is that am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu you can use the [Ondrej Sury PHP PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5). After adding this PPA to your system, you can install the oauth extension package with `aptitude install php5-oauth`.

Instructions for adding a PPA depend on which Ubuntu version you're on. For 12.04 you need to install `python-software-properties` and then you can use `add-apt-repository` command.